# MS Word chops characters after a newline

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word-2013

I have this problem where when a line has reached it's max and auto "new line"s (or if I press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd>, the new words/characters are chopped off.

I have already have played around with line spacing and it just doesn't change anything.

Here is an example:

[image]

My paragraph settings in layout:

[image]

Comment: What are your spacing "before" and "after" settings? What is your line spacing setting? Please [edit] your question and add a screen shot of the Paragraph Indents and Spacings dialog.

Comment: @DavidPostill Done.

Comment: Please the whole dialog like this image http://content.gcflearnfree.org/topics/233/line_paragraph_dialog_box2.png

Comment: @DavidPostill i appologise, it's in there, but in french, if you don't understand something i can explain it.

Comment: What is your font size? I'm guessing your font size is more than 14pt? Try setting "Interligne" to 1.5.

Comment: Thank you, it made it look too wide between lines, but it works good, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Characters chopped after a newline

The line spacing is set incorrectly. It is set to exactly `14 pt` and the font size is (probably) larger than `14 pt`.

You should choose a different value for the line spacing:

- A value of `1.5 lines` is normal.
- The spacing can be 'fine tuned' by using different `xx pt` sizes (but make sure they are **larger** than the font size).